# How to use session attribute (captcha code) in custom JSR-303 Bean Validation constraint?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I want to move my captcha-code validation from Spring MVC controller to class representing posted from, because it is the last element that is not checked using JSR-303 API.

**Basically, how to inject HttpSession or HttpServletRequest into JSR-303 contraint or Spring @ModelAttribute representing posted form data** to validate captcha input?

Suppose we have a captcha code in "captcha_code" session attribute, how to write JSR-303 custom constraint that will compare input to that session attribute? Like:

```
class RegisterForm {

 ... email, password etc. ...

 @NotNull
 @Length( min = 6 , max = 6 )
 @EqualsToSessionAttribute("captcha_code") // How to make such constraint?
 private String captchaCode;

 ...
}
```

Eventually, how to inject request/session to form object so I can use my (custom) `@FieldMatch` JSR-303 annotation that forces two form fields to be equal.

The main problem is that even if we could inject session into custom constraint, object representing constraint is created only with first validation and then cached as singleton bean.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your Validator spring managed with [`@Configurable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable).

> The main problem is that [.. the] constraint is created only with first validation and then cached as singleton bean.

This would be a problem if the injected bean is not a [scoped proxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection). At least `HttpServletRequest` is such a proxy so you will find a safe way to your session.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom annotation, let's call it **@myVal**, which compares the captcha session attribute and the text you enter in the form. This is how you can make such a thing:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = CapVal.class)
@Target({METHOD,FIELD,ANNOTATION_TYPE,CONSTRUCTOR,PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyVal {
    String message() default "Captcha is not correct!";
    Class<?>[] groups() default{};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {}; 
}
```

and

```
public class CapVal implements ConstraintValidator<MyVal,String> {

    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyVal myVal) {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (s.compareToIgnoreCase(session.getAttribute("captcha_code").toString()) == 0) {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

now put this **@myVal** annotation above 'captchaCode' field in the POJO and it's done